# How to prevent div from growing past certain page width?

Tags: html, css

So let's say my div is set to be `width:20%`, but on a really large display (say, past 1500px) you'd like to stop the div from growing any larger. So 20% width, but once it reaches 1500px it just stops expanding. How should I go about this? I'm still new to responsive design.

Comment: -1. You could have googled it.

Comment: @bjb568 I think it's difficult to Google when you don't know that the feature exists. After all it could have been some sort of DHTML trick. However, with that said, i would advise that Tom Maxwell just goes to w3schools.com and reads through the available tags and styles.

Comment: @Volodya Why? Just assume it does, and if the search doesn't turn up anything, ask.

Comment: @Volodya People should never go to w3schools.com. If you haven't visit w3fools.com, I assume you still don't know about that. Encourage people to go to good reference sites like sitepoint and mozilla docs but please no w3schools.

Comment: @DhirajShah w3fools reads like a rant, i found not a single example of something that is actually "wrong" only statements that it is. i come from a skeptic community, and we have a saying 'source or stfu'... which is very applicable here.

Comment: @bjb568 Because HTML has gaping holes in it the size of Everest. I still cannot believe that <a> does not differentiate between 'display' and 'download' and forces you to hack together code for changing of the content disposition on *every* server that you want to control the bahaviour.

Comment: @Volodya When it's about references, if the first thing that comes to your mind is w3schools, then I can understand where you are coming from. There are clear reasons why w3schools should be avoided but still you don't see. That's a pity, man. If you can give yourself high quality education, would you even bother about average ones? Anyways, it's not a debate place, so lets stop :)

Comment: @Volodya https://www.google.com/search?q=%3Ca%3E+download+html&oq=%3Ca%3E+download+html&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-US&espv=1

Comment: @bjb568 i stand corrected on this point

Answer (score 1):

set `max-width` and `min-width` by which you can control the size of the div

You could set your css like

```
    div{
         width:20%;
         max-width:1633px;  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `max-width: 1500px;` you can limit the width.

Answer (score 0):

```
#selector {
  max-width: 300px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {max-width: 1500px;}
```

Pretty simple. Just use max-width.